# Increase value of an identity column in SQL Server without dropping and recreating the table

Tags: sql-server-2008, identity

In a table, I have an ID column, that is an Identity int.

How can I make it so that the next row inserted will get identity 10000 (I believe this is called the identity seed) - without dropping and recreating the table?

I need to do this because of a uniqueness issue with an external service, the app accesses.

Comment: Please check with this link and try http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/668042/SQL-Server-Auto-Identity-Column-Value-Jump-Is

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (yourtable, reseed, 9999)
```

This will make the next entry 10000.

Comment: I may be off one here, can't remember.

Comment: 10000 or 10001 does not matter in this case - your code works, thanks! :)

Comment: Doing it through the GUI drops and recreates the table - I Know because that's what I did before asking the question, and got a warning smacked in my face. ;)

Comment: Ah, good point there. I'll edit to revert back to my old statement of not stating anything else.

Answer (score 6):

This should do it:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (MyTableName, RESEED, 9999)
```

Comment: That will make the next entry be 10001. I made the same mistake previously.

Comment: @TheTXI - You are correct and I've updated accordingly. Thanks.